# Android app fails to connect to cellular internet while on a call

Tags: java, android

hi all i am having issues over cellular network while on a phone call ringing. here is my code:

```
 String request = con.getHTML("http://something.com/xxx/yyyy?number=" + numb);
 System.out.println(request);
```

And here is the getHTML function:

```
public String getHTML(String url) {
         String inputLine= "";
         String returno = "";
        try {
            URL oracle = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

           boolean body = false;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(inputLine);
                    returno+="\n"+inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return returno;
    }
```

Well then.. everithing works pretty fine while using wifi network, i get response and the code goes smooth. When i run the same app while on phone call ringing using cellular network, the response from the api never arrives, or just after phone call is over turning 501 status...
Is there some permisison i need to give to the app in order to use carrier network?